# ORACLE JDBC Batch execution doesn't return actual count of affected rows

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, batch-processing

I'm working on an application where I'm using **JDBC** and **Oracle11**.

I have hundreds of thousands of records in my table `tbltest` which I'm updating via **JDBC** batch execution. So consider it as *one id = one query*.

**My Requirement:** I want to track which `id`s got successfully updated and which do not exist in db.

Following is my code:

```
String sql = "UPDATE TBLTEST SET STATUS = 'CANCEL' WHERE ID = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
Connection connection = getConnection(); // I'm getting this connection properly
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

for (String id : idList) { // idList is a List of String being passed to my method
    preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
    preparedStatement.addBatch();
}
int[] affectedRecords = preparedStatement.executeBatch();

System.out.println("Records affected:"+Arrays.toString(affectedRecords));
int success = preparedStatement.getUpdateCount();
System.out.println(success + " Total updated");
```

My records are successfully being updated as per the `idList` provided. According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) Javadoc, in `affectedRecords`, I should get actual no. of records updated by each update query because I'm not getting any exception.
Instead I get the array `affectedRecords` filled with *-2* only. So if `idList` contains 5 elements:

**Actual output:**

```
Records affected: [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2]
5 Total updated
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Records affected: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
5 Total updated
```

I searched this issue on internet and came across some posts like these:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3691652?start=0&tstart=0
https://community.oracle.com/thread/1046798?tstart=0

But the the solutions provided in those posts also don't help me as I'm already using **ojdbc6.jar** only.

So is there any solution or alternate to this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found it. The problem was related to `PreparedStatement`.

According to Javadoc by Oracle [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28767), I cannot get the count of records affected by each query when I use `PreparedStatement`. So when I converted my code to `Statement` it worked perfectly.

Reference Note:

> Update Counts in the Oracle Implementation of Standard Batching If a
>   statement batch is processed successfully, then the integer array, or
>   update counts array, returned by the statement executeBatch call will
>   always have one element for each operation in the batch. In the Oracle
>   implementation of standard update batching, the values of the array
>   elements are as follows:
>
> For a prepared statement batch, it is not possible to know the number
>   of rows affected in the database by each individual statement in the
>   batch. Therefore, all array elements have a value of -2. According to
>   the JDBC 2.0 specification, a value of -2 indicates that the operation
>   was successful but the number of rows affected is unknown.
>
> For a generic statement batch, the array contains the actual update
>   counts indicating the number of rows affected by each operation. The
>   actual update counts can be provided only in the case of generic
>   statements in the Oracle implementation of standard batching.
>
> For a callable statement batch, the server always returns the value 1
>   as the update count, irrespective of the number rows affected by each
>   operation.

Answer (score 3):

`-2` is `SUCCESS_NO_INFO` so it doesn't tell you how many rows were updated for this element in the batch. However, starting in 11.2.0.3, the JDBC thin driver will tell you the exact number of updated rows for each element of the batch. This was one of the key new features of that version. It works with `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

As the [threads you link to describe](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1046798?tstart=3), it is NOT an issue of `ojdbc6.jar` vs `ojdbc5.jar` but vs current versions of those vs. older versions of those.

So make sure you get the very newest version of the driver:

> pick up  ojdbc5.jar if you run the program with java 5
>
> ojdbc6.jar if you run the program with java 6
>
> then add/replace orai18n.jar

Also make sure that java picks up the correct version, possibly by using the `-verbose` switch for java.

Comment: Thanks for reply Jens. But I don't have any other version of ojdbc jar. I've already mentioned in my question that I'm using ojdbc6.jar. I'm using Java 6 only. I don't have Java 5 installed.

Comment: Yes, and this is irrelevant, as stated in my answer and in the thread linked in my question and your answer. There are tons of different ojdbc6.jars out there. And you need a recent one. No where have you stateted, that you obtained a fresh version of the driver from oracle, and verified that it actually gets used.

Comment: That also is not helping.